# Style import works in development server but not on production in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```js
import "../styles.css";
import styles from "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import "react-owl-carousel2/lib/styles.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store/store"

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  return 
  <Provider store={store} ><Component {...pageProps} /></Provider>;
}
export default App;
```

react-owl-carousel2/lib/styles.css and styles doesnt work on the production server

> this is the postcss.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
        ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? {
              "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": {
                content: ["./components/**/*.js", "./pages/**/*.js"],
                defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
              }
            }
          : {})
      }
    };
```

Comment: Can you share your `postcss.config.json`, `package.json` and `next.config.json`? Also try deleting the `.next` directory and re-building the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on nextjs github page. here is the link - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem in a project once,
Some of styles were not working correctly when I published them to production server.

So, try this trick, hopefully it works for you as well.
It is a small webpack configuration in `next.config.js`

Add the following in return statement:

```
return {
    webpack: (config) => {
      config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
        common: {
          name: "common",
          chunks: "all",
        },
      };

      return config;
    },
  };
```